# Count written records in Spark with threads

Tags: apache-spark, listener

I am using `onTaskEnd` Spark listener to get the number of records written into file like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}

var recordsWritten: Long = 0L

val rowCountListener: SparkListener = new SparkListener() {
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
    synchronized {
      recordsWritten += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
    }
  }
}

def rowCountOf(proc: => Unit): Long = {
  recordsWritten = 0L
  spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(rowCountListener)
  try {
    proc
  } finally {
    spark.sparkContext.removeSparkListener(rowCountListener)
  }
  recordsWritten
}

val rc = rowCountOf { (1 to 100).toDF.write.csv(s"test.csv") }
println(rc)

=> 100
```

However trying to run multiple actions in threads this obviously breaks:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).par.foreach { i =>
  val rc = rowCountOf { (1 to 100).toDF.write.csv(s"test${i}.csv") }
  println(rc)
}

=> 600
=> 700
=> 750
```

I can have each thread declare its own variable, but spark context is still shared and I am unable to reckognize to which thread does specific `SparkListenerTaskEnd` event belong to. Is there any way to make it work?

(Right, maybe I could just make it separate spark jobs. But it's just a single piece of the program, so for the sake of simplicity I would prefer to stay with threads. In the worst case I'll just execute it serially or forget about counting records...)

Answer (score -1):

A bit hackish but you could use accumulators as a filtering side-effect

```
val acc = spark.sparkContext.longAccumulator("write count")
df.filter { _ =>
  acc.add(1)
  true
}.write.csv(...)
println(s"rows written ${acc.count}")
```

Comment: If I understand caveats section of [this article](https://www.edureka.co/blog/spark-accumulators-explained), when used in a filter I risk double counting in case some executors are lost, isn't this the case?

Comment: Might be but the spark metrics are also implemented internally using accumulators so not sure if they are guaranteed to be exact either https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/OutputMetrics.scala#L43

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy You are correct. If you need the exact number accumulators doesn't handle lost nodes and can count with duplicates.

Comment: So perhaps `cache` and `count` is the way to go if you need the exact count